# Does anyone know the word for a question asked with the intent to injure or insult?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone know the word for a question asked with the intent to injure or insult?  I know there is term for it, but I can't find it anywhere.  It's driving me crazy.

Example:  Are you blind, or just stupid?

Oh, and it's not *rhetorical*.  There is a more specific term.

Edit:  It's not sarcasm.  There is an actual grammatical term to describe this sort of question.

Comment: It's a good question - I'm not sure what you call that, an outright insult phrased as a question.  Just TBC< you're familiar with **rhetorical question** right?  Maybe that's the phrase you're after.

Comment: Do you mean a [pejorative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pejorative) question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're wanting here is either *epiplexis*:

> Asking questions in order to chide, to express grief, or to inveigh. A kind of rhetorical question.
>
> Examples
>
> Why died I not from the womb? why did I not give up the ghost when I came out of the belly? —Job 3:11

or *erotema*:

> The rhetorical question. To affirm or deny a point strongly by asking it as a question.
>
> Generally, as Melanchthon has noted, the rhetorical question includes an emotional dimension, expressing wonder, indignation, sarcasm, etc.
>
> Examples
>
> Just why are you so stupid?

(Both those are from BYU's whipass *[Silva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu)*)

Comment: Erotema seems most apropos to this.

Comment: Epiplexis!  Yes!  That's the word I was looking for.  Rob Short, you are my hero!

Comment: @Coffeeshopkitty you should accept this answer, to show that the question has been answered!

Comment: @Mari-LouA My apologies.  I didn't realize I hadn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The example you gave is of a [*loaded question*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question), a [*suggestive question*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suggestive_question) or a [*presuppositional question*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presupposition). It also offers the speaker's interlocutor a [*false dilemma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma).

(Links are to definitions and explanations of these terms in Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a single word to describe this. You might call it a dysphemistic question.

[Dysphemism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism)

Answer (score 0):

The particular example question might fall under *Aporia* (though the term doesn't apply strictly to questions, but you could talk about an *aporetic question*). Quotes from OED:

> 1589   G. Puttenham Arte Eng. Poesie iii. xix. 189   Aporia, or the
>   Doubtfull. [So] called..because oftentimes we will seeme to cast
>   perils, and make doubt of things when by a plaine manner of speech wee
>   might affirme or deny him. 
>   1656   J. Smith Myst. Rhetorique 150  Aporia is a figure whereby the Speaker sheweth that he doubteth,
>   either where to begin for the multitude of matters, or what to do or
>   say in some strange or ambiguous thing.

However, aporia doesn't have to be used in service of insult.

Comment: I’m not quite sure [that that one fits](https://mcl.as.uky.edu/glossary-rhetorical-terms#8).