# What's the term for "blame disguised as a question"?

Tags: questions, rhetorical-devices

Is there a term for disguising blame as a question?

For example,  when someone is late, someone sarcastically says

> Wow you're early, did you wake up late?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know the word for a question asked with the intent to injure or insult?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197196/does-anyone-know-the-word-for-a-question-asked-with-the-intent-to-injure-or-insu) [epiplexis]

Comment: That sample question makes no sense as an example of "blame disguised".  The question is "Did you wake up late?" and overtly refers to lateness.  The statement "Wow you're early" is an assertion (a blatantly false one if the person is late, and thus laden with sarcasm) and is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Epiplexis

> In rhetoric, ***epiplexis*** is an interrogative figure of speech in which questions are asked in order to rebuke or reproach rather than to elicit answers. ([Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/epiplexis-rhetoric-term-1690664))

Here's some classical examples:

> What shall it profit a man, if he gains the whole world, and lose his own soul? (Mark 8:36)
>
> Have you eyes?
> Could you on this fair mountain leave to feed,
> And batten on this moor? Ha! have you eyes? (Hamlet by William Shakespeare)
>
> Did you have a brain tumour for breakfast? ([Heathers, 1988](https://www.bfi.org.uk/features/seven-things-we-love-about-heathers#:%7E:text=Dialogue%20to%20die%20for&text=His%20script%20offers%20a%20masterclass,%2C%20bulimia%27s%20so%20%2787.%E2%80%9D))